# automate call stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, call

I think this hasn't been answered before.

I have a stored procedure which enters records based on specific criteria in MySQL. A record is added when the Call procedure is entered in SQL. I was wondering how I can automate the CALL procedure without me having to type CALL procedure to enter the stored procedure.

Thanks

SS

I have since created the event. A very short but effective piece of code.

```
CREATE EVENT addlesson
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 7 DAY
STARTS CURRENT_DATE() 
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
ENABLE
DO 
INSERT INTO timetbl VALUES (CURRENT_DATE(), 'MAT02', 'MATHS', '1800');
```

use EVERY for recurrence and PRESERVE to keep event.

Comment: Where does the procedure get its record data from? PHP or data that already exists on the database?

Comment: It already exists within the database. However, for me the Event Scheduler is more appropriate for my application. I can add the information without having to refer to the Stored Procedure.

Comment: Great.... I was going to suggest the vastly underused CREATE EVENT if it was all on the database already, no need for cron jobs or php scripts or anything external at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In MySQL 5.0.2 and newer you can create trigger.**

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html

Triggers are activated by SQL statements (you can define trigger that runs sql after every insert into some table for example).

**In MySQL 5.1.12 and newer you can use event.**

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-overview.html

Events are activated by date/time.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. The event scheduler was EXACTLY what I was looking for.